# Comma after this introductory phrase—necessary or helpful?

Tags: commas

I can't quite decide whether or not this comma is necessary (by CMoS standards) or provides a helpful pause even if it's not strictly needed. I'm also debating whether this sentence needs a "that" after "clear."

> From the opening lines,  it’s clear The Girl at the center of these
>   poems is damaged...

For some context, this book of poems refers to "The Girl" as her name, as a sort of everywoman.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest this: "From the opening lines, it’s clear that "The Girl" at the center of these poems is damaged."

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the comma is necessary depends entirely on what meaning you want to convey.

Is *from the opening lines* providing additional information, or is its presence essential to the sentence?

Syntactically, because the comma *is* there (and how the rest of the sentence is constructed), what precedes it is a dependent clause, which makes the information nonessential.

This:

> From the opening lines, it's clear The Girl at the centre of these poems is damaged.

Means this:

> It's clear (and was from the start) The Girl at the centre of these poems is damaged.

Or simply:

> It's clear The Girl at the centre of these poems is damaged.

---

But if the author had intended *from the opening lines* to be essential information, then the comma should not have been used.

This:

> From the opening lines it's clear The Girl at the centre of these poems is damaged.

Means this:

> The opening lines make it clear The Girl at the centre of these poems is damaged.

Or:

> It's clear because of the opening lines The Girl at the centre of these poems is damaged.

---

Note that this may be a distinction that is lost in some interpretations. For instance, the comma may be viewed stylistically rather than syntactically.

In other words, the version of the sentence that has a comma could *still* be seen as providing essential information, with the comma serving only to indicate a pause rather than to indicate a dependent clause.

---

As for the use of *that*, it's mostly a style choice. It may or may not sound better to you or a reader, and in some cases its presence can help to more easily parse a sentence. (While in others it could be considered unnecessary or even distracting.)

Neal Whitman discusses this in the the blog post ["When to Delete 'That'"](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-to-delete-that).

He says that "newspapers are often guilty of ignoring the difference between bridge verbs and non-bridge verbs and deleting a 'that' after verbs where it would sound better to leave it in."

He further says:

> Sometimes, omitting a "that" after a non-bridge verb goes beyond being slightly awkward and can actually be confusing. Here’s an example from Bryan Garner’s *Modern American Usage*:
>
> - Son acknowledges being a member of a minority . . . may have helped him turn his eyes abroad early.
>
> The trouble here is that "acknowledge" can be a transitive verb. So when a noun phrase comes after it, such as "being a member of a minority," the reader might just take it as a direct object: “Son acknowledges being a member of a minority.” But whoops! The sentence keeps going, and the reader has to go back and reparse it. Garner calls this a miscue; sentences that produce miscues like this are called garden-path sentences.

Comment: Jason, 

Thanks so much for your detailed reply! It sounds like leaving the comma is the best based on our intended meaning, as you phrased it:

"It's clear (and was from the start) The Girl at the centre of these poems is damaged."